# After I knit the surface some blue sketch lines presist

Tags: cad, solidworks, surface-modelling

Knit command on SW 2017 results blue sketch lines even with all surfaces selected [image]

I was following the steps in a tutorial and I am sure i got them all 100% correct up to that point.

what could be the reason?

Comment: One or two steps were not correct, check them all again - even a comma one space out can be sufficient : compilers are picky picky picky...

Comment: You need to upload share your file if you want diagnosis, that screenshot is not really sufficient. In the panel on the left during the Kint command, there is an option to close gaps - try expanding the tolerance sliders to their maximum value so all gaps are captured, and then tick all the boxes to close all gaps.

Comment: Those aren't "blue sketch lines" they're open edges.

Answer (score 1):

[image: gaps not auto knitted]

If your gaps are larger than your knitting tolerance, then they will not automatically be closed. Pull the sliders to the minimum and maximum respectively to ensure that all gaps are shown, and either increase your tolerance or manually select the larger gaps that you would like to knit.

P.S. This screenshot is not taken from the same model as you - I just spent a long time trying to force some significant gaps - not easy to have an error when you're trying to get one!!